# Leer un csv y guardar los datos en un ArrayList de objetos

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, backend

Como seria la mejor forma de guardar el archivo csv en un ArrayList de objetos?
Tengo un archivo csv de mas de 20 mil lineas e mas de 25 atributos. Quiero poder leer los datos del archivo y guardarlos en una lista. Lo mejor seria una lista de objetos.
Hasta ahora tengo esto

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    String archCSV = "C:\\Users\\c\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Dados/Products.csv";
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(archCSV));
    String[] fila = null;
    
    
        int i = 0;
    List<Produtos> prods = new ArrayList<>();
    Produtos p[] = new Produtos [20000];
    
    while((fila = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
        
        p[i] = new Produtos();
        p[i].setId(i, fila[0]); //Ejemplo de como pretendo guardar todos los datos del archivo en cada atributo de la clase Produtos
        prods.add(p[i]);
        
        i++;
    }
    csvReader.close();
```

Estoy usando opencsv pra leer el archivo. Cuando ejecuto este código me da error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.produtos.Produtos.<init>(Produtos.java:10)
    at com.produtos.App.main(App.java:36)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hay partes de la pregunta en portugues? podrias traducirlas?

Comment: Muchas gracias, las partes en portugues ya las cambié. Estoy realmente perdida en este trabajo, podrias ayudarme con eso?

Comment: Mostra el error completo porfa.. y traduci el titulo!

Comment: ok, creo que ya estan todos los cambios prontos...

Comment: Estas creando un array de Productos con 20.000 objetos y un arrayList<Productos> donde se guardan 20.000 objetos y te quedas sin memoria. Intentá eliminar el array y reemplázalo por un único objeto producto,  e inicia el con ArrayList<>(20001). ( no entiendo la función de i es para garantizar el orden? ) Si no funciona tu programa necesita reservar más memoria. Opencsv te permite copiar directamente a objetos pero hay que evaluar la performance.